# How to Enable Default S3 Bucket Encryption Programmatically

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using the S3 Java API and I want to enable the default encryption (AES-256) option for buckets that I create programmatically through the Java API. I can't seem to find the correct API call or documentation that describes how to enable this option through code. Is there a way to do this through the Java API and not have to explicitly enable it on the S3 Web Console?

I don't have any issues uploading objects that have the default server side encryption set using the ObjectMetadata class, but can't seem to find the option to enable it on the bucket it self. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3EncryptionClient.html Did you see that? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like my S3 API was out of date. After updating to the latest version (1.11.257) I now have access to com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.SetBucketEncryptionRequest